# Add active class to routerlink in angular 4

Tags: angular, routerlink, routerlinkactive

I would like to add an active class when changing routes. 
I have an  link in one component (home page) which redirects to other component (details page).

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard/details" (click)="Clicked()"</a>
```

Now when I return back from details page to home page, I want to have the a link to be active telling the users that this link has been clicked.

I tried using **routerLinkActive**, but that doesn't seem to be working.

html

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard/details" routerLinkActive="active-link" (click)="Clicked()"</a>
```

css

```
.active-link {
    color:red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `(click)="Clicked()</a>` should be `(click)="Clicked()"</a>`

Comment: that was typo while posting. edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add class name on click event. try this.

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard/details" [ngClass]="{'active-link':clicked}" routerLinkActive="active-link" (click)="Clicked()"</a>
```

in .ts file

```
clicked: boolean = false;

Clicked() {
this.clicked = true;
}
```

Comment: may be because i used "active" class name instead of "active-link". can you try [ngClass]="{'active-link':clicked}".

Comment: when I'm coming back to home page from details page, this.clicked is showing false

Comment: where did you defined that event and that link? in details component.

Comment: that link and event is in home component.

Comment: okay so the reason it is false because when you click that link and redirect to dashboard component, home component get destroyed. That what i think, if this is true then to make it work you have to create a shared service and store that boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }
u have eput this one beside the  like its work

Answer (score 0):

Solutions :

1. Can use `localStorage` to store the information of link clicked.
2. Can use router `queryParams` to store the info.
   Capture the info using `ActivatedRoutes` :

   `this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(
   params => {
   this.enableCard = JSON.parse(params.get('enableCard'));
   })`

Not the best solution, but the work around.